# Obj-c - Wrong keyboard height is returned?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get the height of the iOS keyboard so that I can move my view up when the keyboard is animated. However, I keep getting the value 258 returned (which, isn't correct, as it pushes my view up too high?) Why is this happening? Code below:

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

}
    - (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

        NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];

        NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

        CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
      self.keyboardHeight = keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;


    }

    - (void) animateTextView:(BOOL) up
    {

        const int movementDistance = self.keyboardHeight;

        const float movementDuration = 0.3f;
        int movement= movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);


        [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

        self.upView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.upView.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationStops)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get height of keyboard, you should use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification.`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

}
```

If you use `UITabBarController`, you have to calculate frame without tab bar height. You can get tab bar height with the code below.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height
```

Comment: Still returns height of 258 - no dice.

Comment: Where did you log this value? Do you use `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Yes, the view is embedded in a UITabBarController. I log the value inside animateTextView and inside keyboardWillChange.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can take a look. If it doesn't work, please update question with the line you log the value of keyboard height

Comment: Ahh yes, subtracting the tab bar size works like a charm. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You should register UIKeyboardWillShowNotification for observing the keyboard height.

```
1)  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

2) you can also try this code :

```
(void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
}
```